# C++ test last character of a string

Tags: c++, string, find, character

I want to test if the var string is terminated with a '\n' or not, in order to detect and remove some incomplete incoming variables from a stream async socket. It seems the following code doesn't work properly. Why ?

```
string var;
char *rest = nullptr;
char *pVar = nullptr;
istringstream iss(sReadBuffer); // Put into a stream            
while (getline(iss, var)) // Default delimiter '\n' or EOF
{                       
    int size = var.size();
    pVar = _strdup(var.c_str()); // Cast string to char * for later use (strstr,...)

    if(var[size] != '\n') // If incomplete variable found (not newline ended)...
    {
        debug("Incomplete variable found : ", pVar, "\n");
        rest = pVar;                                
        break;
    }

//... proceed with variable normally if they are complete
```

Comment: I'm still fathoming on how `getline` kept the newline.

Answer (score 2):

`getline()` discards the newline. If you want to test for EOF, test the `stringstream` object itself.

Answer (score 1):

`var[size]` accesses the string out of bounds. But you can use the [`std::string::back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back) member to get a reference to the last element.

```
if(var.back() != '\n')
```

That avoids potential indexing errors. The code above assumes `var` is not empty. You can check with `std::string::empty()`. For example,

```
if((!var.empty()) && (var.back() != '\n'))
```

How you expect to find a `\n` in a string read with `getline` is another matter.

Comment: Better test for a nonempty string before `var.back()`.

Comment: @Lingxi Agreed. I added a mention of that, and an example.

Comment: @JorenHeit To avoid any ambiguity. Sometimes people get confused.

Comment: Thanks. You guys mean getline() will delete the '\n' at the end of the "tokens" ?